# Return cell that contains all of these things

Tags: excel, formulas

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now, so maybe someone will be able to help. If not, I guess I'll have to rethink my strategy.
I'm trying to set up a cutting sheet for use on the machines in our factory, which can also give an estimated time on the machine (based on a database, we need this for costing) and my basic idea is this:

For one job, the user selects the machine, the material, the component, and the different cuts that are needed on this piece (shape and size of holes, edging of components, etc.), then the sheet returns the estimated time based on those variables.
The tricky bit: I have the database set up as a long list with each combination of variables, like so : `Machine 1 - Wood - Post - 14mm holes - etc.`

But the user may not always put the variables in the same order, preventing the use of CONCATENATE and VLOOKUP, so I'm trying to find a formula that looks for the cell which contains the items that the user has selected and returns the value of an associated cell. Basically, a VLOOKUP where it searches for the bits, rather than an exact string.

I have this formula which returns True or False if a specified cell contains all the items in a list:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(things,A1)))=COUNTA(things)`

But I don't know how to check all the combinations in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Develop a user form so you will have control over the data input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need some sort of database backend and queries heavily laden with wildcards, but perhaps this can get you started.

In M2 as a standard formula,

```
=INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(G$1:INDEX(G:G,MATCH("zzz",G:G)))/
                         (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I2,G$1:INDEX(G:G,MATCH("zzz",G:G))))*
                          ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J2,G$1:INDEX(G:G,MATCH("zzz",G:G))))*
                          ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K2,G$1:INDEX(G:G,MATCH("zzz",G:G))))*
                          ISNUMBER(SEARCH(L2,G$1:INDEX(G:G,MATCH("zzz",G:G))))), 1))
```

[image: comp_mach_cut_matl]

The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) evaluates four [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3)s and returns the first row that matches all four.

Comment: I put that into my sheet and fitted it to my needs and it's worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/MAX(IF(MMULT(IFERROR(SEARCH(D2:G2,A2:A6),-(10^6)),TRANSPOSE(D1:G1<>"")*1)>0,
B2:B6))),"Combination not found")
```

As an array formula (press ctrl + shift + enter rather than enter when entering).

The assumption here is that entries in column A are unique and items in each entry in column A are unique as well (i.e. no "a - b - b - d"). Also items given by the users must be unique.